# Can't ssh into remote server unless I login locally on the server first

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh

I've set up ubuntu server on an old desktop and was able to log in with password no problem. I then set up ssh keys and disallowed logging in with passwords. I now have this weird issue where I get a public key denied error when trying to ssh remotely UNLESS I connect a monitor to the old desktop and log in to the server locally, then log in to the server remotely using the keys - this works.

I've checked the permissions for both the .ssh files/folders on both machines and they're fine: 755 for home directories, 700 for .ssh, 644 for id_rsa.pub, and 600 for id_rsa and authorized_keys.

Any idea what's going on here?

Comment: What do you mean by "ssh locally"? Should that be "remotely"?

Comment: @terdon yes, sorry.  I try ssh'ing remotely and it fails unless I connect a monitor to the server and login with a password locally.  Then I'm able to ssh remotely.

Comment: OK, please [edit] and tell us i) exactly how you set up passwordless access ii) explain exactly how you disabled password access. You might also want to show us the relevant `~/.ssh/config` and `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` files.

Comment: Are you using encrypted home directory on the server?

Comment: That was it.  Thanks for your help.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys#Troubleshooting for anyone who faces similar issues.

Comment: Adding `ecryptfs-mount-privatecd $HOME` to ~/.profile is the last missing step to get ones Home directory to mount normally after the workaround. Source: https://stephenreescarter.net/encrypted-home-directories-ssh-key-authentication/

Answer (score 7):

The answer was as Michal Politowski said in the comments.  Encrypted home directory contained the .ssh folder, so it wasn't accessible to ssh command until I logged on locally and decrypted the folder.  Solution was to create /home/ssh/%user%/ and place the authorized_keys file there, then direct ssh to look there via sshd_config. See comments for link to useful web page.

Comment: It would be a good idea to add the link from the comment to the answer, I think. And probably also the actual configuration steps, so the answer is self-contained.

Comment: My home directory is not encrypted and I still have this problem of not being able to login remotely unless logged in locally.

Answer (score 5):

It's the network adapter. It's configured to only be available to YOUR user.

You must set the network adapter to be available to other/all users. In GNOME, this is done in the network adapter settings as a checkbox "Make available to other users".

Without this, your user will need to login locally first before the network adapter starts listening for standard services like SSH.

Comment: This was giving me a huge headache.  "Make available to other users" sounded like it was sharing my wifi so I had disabled it.